# Android curved menu like camera app

Tags: android, menu

I would like to know if there is a project / library to mimic the official android camera app option menus.

The latest camera app gets a touch menu to set up flash options etc 
The rendering is a sort of flat pie control.

Is there anything like this available for developer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

- [ArcMenu](https://github.com/daCapricorn/ArcMenu), is not the same appearance of the stock Android camera but it's similar:

  [image] [image]
- [Radial Menu Widget](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/10/radial-menu-widget/):

  [image]

Comment: Thanks! Radial menu sounds promising. It is a shame google doesn't provide the api for the menu they provide in their stock app... I love pie menus when you have a full screen view, it is so convenient.